# Google Analytics - Demographics - IDFA

Tags: ios, cordova, google-analytics, idfa

I have been Googling this to try and confirm - My understanding is Apple now reject apps using IDFA without actually serving Adverts. For the demographics feature of Google analytics the documentation says that IDFA collection must be enabled.

There are lots of articles around how the latest version of the Google analytics IOS SDK no longer requires the collection of IDFA by default.

To gather demographic data though - can someone please confirm if you still need to enable this option? Is it no longer possible to collect demographic data without serving ads using Google analytics?

Thanks heaps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When submitting the app, specify that you are using it to attribute campaigns served outside of the app. Works for us for over a year.

Comment: Hi Sash! When was the last time you submitted an app version this way?

Comment: Last Friday But I believe it was fixed by the Google team a while ago

Answer (score 5):

I am using IDFA exclusively for getting demographic info for Google Analytics.

I chose the option:
"Attribute this app installation to a previously served advertisement".

And my app was approved. Cheers! :-D

Comment: Felipe, I am trying to do the same thing, but I cannot "Validate tracking code" in the dashboard. Can I get some help? Here's my question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36703659/3344977

Comment: Hi, i am also using demographic  in ios app, am enabled tracker.allowIDFACollection = YES; in my xcode project and  my Google analytics account shows repost like screen report and location report etc etc, But "Demographic" not working its not generating any report i don't know what i am missing . please help me to fixe  my issue.

Comment: As I remember, it took some days before having enough information to show up on the report. Are you locating correctly the report on Google Analytics? It is located under the Audience item in the left bar.