# Cant validate tracking code for demographic reports using Google Analytics iOS SDK with IDFA

Tags: ios, google-analytics, idfa

I'm trying to gather `Demographics and Interest Reports` for my iOS app users using the `Google Analytics iOS SDK`.

I have enabled `Demographics and Interest Reports` in my Google Analytics dashboard. I also installed the `GoogleIDFASupport` pod (Cocoapods), and set the following code in my app delegate:

```
#if DEBUG
#else
    let gAnalytics = GAI.sharedInstance()
    gAnalytics.defaultTracker.allowIDFACollection = true
#endif
```

I have been testing the app multiple times, and running in Release scheme on my iPhone, and the app is also currently waiting for review in the App Store.

When I login to the Google Analytics dashboard, and go to the `Demographics and Interest Reports` section, it tells me that I have enabled it, but also presents a button that says "Validate tracking code". If I click the button, the page just refreshes and tells me that `"Your Analytics tracking code does not include the necessary support for the Demographics and Interest reports."`

How can I validate the tracking code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just ignoring the warning and skipping the validation. The demographics stats have been showing up just fine.

Comment: Same happened to me.